# Returning Cell Index based on Cell Color in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to compare the color of a cell with that of a range and return the corresponding Column-Index of the cell in that range where the color matches in excel.

Match Colour

[image: MatchColour]

I came up with the below vba code, but it isn't working.

```
Function MATCHCOLOUR(rColor As Range, rRange As Range) As Long

Dim lCol As Long
Dim vResult As Long

lCol = rColor.Interior.Color

If rRange.Interior.Color = lCol Then
    vResult = rRange.ColumnIndex
End If

MATCHCOLOUR = vResult

End Function
```

Sample Result: `MATCHCOLOUR(A1,B1:B10)` should return 5 (i.e. columnindex) where colour of A1 and B5 match.

Comment: I'm sorry , but your screen-shot does not match your sample result using your formula, can you show a sample of data that is relevant ?

Comment: I've never heard of `.ColumnIndex`. Perhaps you mean `.Column`?

Comment: In your sample result, if B5 and A1 have the same color, and the result you are looking for is 5, then you mean `Rows` not `Columns`, and it should be 4, and not 5, No?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what parameter you are trying to get back from your UDF, so my code below contains a few of them.

First, you need to loop through your `Range.Cells`, in my code I assumed once there was a match, you read that Cell's `Column` (or `Row`) and `Exit` the `For` loop.

Second, there are a few possible results you could get, let's use your Sample Result, `MATCHCOLOUR(A1,B1:B10)`, and Cell B5 has the same color has Cell A1:

***Abosulte Column***: the column number of B5 >> retruns 2

***Relative Column***: the relative column number of B% to A1 >> retruns 1

***Absolute Row***: the row number of B5 >> retruns 5

***Relative Row***: the relative row number of B5 to A1 >> retruns 4

---

**Code**

```
Function MATCHCOLOUR(rColor As Range, rRange As Range) As Long

Dim vResult As Long
Dim c As Range

For Each c In rRange.Cells
    If c.Interior.Color = rColor.Interior.Color Then
        ' getting the absolute column number of the match in the Range
        vResult = c.Column

        ' getting the absolute column number of the match in the Range
        vResult = c.Row

        ' getting the relative columns number of the match in the Range and current cell
        vResult = c.Column - rColor.Column

        ' getting the relative rows number of the match in the Range and current cell
        vResult = c.Row - rColor.Row

        Exit For
    End If
Next c

MATCHCOLOUR = vResult

End Function
```

So, running this Function, when trying to get the absolute row of the first occurrence the cells color match, is cell B5 >> will return 5:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try going over the range cell by cell and returning the count in that range. It's a bit brute force, but should cover what you need:

```vba
Function MATCHCOLOUR(rColor As Range, rRange As Range) As Long

    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim vResult As Long
    Dim vFound As Long

    lCol = rColor.Interior.Color
    vResult = 0
    vFound = 0

    For Each rCell In rRange.Cells
        vResult = vResult + 1
        If rCell.Interior.Color = lCol Then
            vFound = 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If vFound = 0 Then
        MATCHCOLOUR = 0
    Else
        MATCHCOLOUR = vResult
    End If

End Function
```